# Do editor errors affect device performance?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

Do errors that come up in the Unity editor affect a game's performance on a device (on Android in particular)?  I'm talking about errors that keep coming continuously during `Update()` such as `NullReferenceException`  and "`Debug.Log`".

I've released the game [Drop Fall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.G_C.DropFall) containing these continuous editor errors. The app suddenly closes & the FPS drops on some devices.

Comment: That is unanswerable without knowing what errors you're talking about. But generally errors are not to be ignored. You fix them before shipping.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. I'm talking about errors that keep coming during `Update()`

Comment: NullReferenceExceptions shouldn't happen and shouldn't be ignored. Your game make go on as if nothing happened, but there is no guarantee it will. Just because you think all is fine, something will bite you at some point in time where you don't want to be bitten. So no, never ever ignore errors.

Comment: I believe that Google can delete your app if is "unsafe for users" not fixing nullpointers can crash the app and/or phone. I also think that the user could start legal actions against you (check the terms of service). However, there isn't any direct hit on performance; just unwanted behaviors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bart is right , you must clear error before get build for android , but , some error like null pointer exceptions will get occurs during run time , and they stop script that got error. beside this , there is no usual effect on performance on your game in device.

Comment: I'm talking about errors that keep coming during `Update()`. I edited the question.

Comment: as i said , error during game , doesn't affect game performance but they can cause logical errors on your game , for that avoid them !
but if you take error on your update , the cods you have after that error may not work and update calls again , and again error ! so if you have error , remove them ;)

Comment: Well I would say they affect indirectly - pushing message on console is very haevy in terms of performance like debugs.